# what is the page table size for a 32-bit process?

Tags: memory, paging

If the page size for a process is 4096 bytes what should be its page table size that it keeps for mapping virtual addresses to physical storage?

Answer (score 0):

A 32 bits process can allocate up to 4G bytes = 1M pages @ 4K. So, a process may need up to one million entries in the page table(s). The page table architecture varies quite a bit between processors, so it's hard to give a more precise answer to such a generic question.